# PHP -- Convert a csv file into a named multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I am a bit new to PHP, and I am having some trouble converting a csv file into a multidimensional array, where each dimension has a name. I need to two distinct named array so that I can use them in a preg_replace statement like the below:

```
$expand_abbrev=preg_replace($contracted_form , $expanded_form , $sentence);
```

the file content are as follows:

contracted_form,expanded_form

'/a./','in dates ante'

'/abbrev./','abbreviation of'

'/Abbrev./','abbreviations'

'/Abd./','Aberdeen'

'/Aberd./','Aberdeen'

'/Aberdeensh./','Aberdeenshire'

This is so far what I have come up with, but it does not achieve the desired output.

```
$abbrev_list=file_get_contents('files/abbreviations.text');
$test=str_getcsv($abbrev_list, ",");
$expand_abbrev=preg_replace($contracted_form, $expanded_form, $sentence);
```

Can anyone help me out with this please ? I have been trying so many times but so far no success.

---- Please allow me to make a clarification, because it seems I might have mislead you. I would like to process a csv file which has two two values per line contracted_form and expanded_form. These two values per line are separated by a comma.

I am not sure how best to approach it, I was thinking perhaps splitting the each line into two arrays like for example each contracted_form is stored in the contracted_from array and each expanded_form is stored in the expanded_form array.

So that preg_replace can replace any instance of contracted_from, encountered in a sentence with its corresponding expanded_form. So for example the following sentence:

Hi sir, I live in a flat in Abd.

So preg_replace(Adb. , Aberdeen,  Hi sir, I live in a flat in Abd.) would result in the below.

Hi sir, I live in a flat in Aberdeen.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28118243/4341572

Comment: If your CSV file contains the values quoted with apostrophes (`'`) as you put them in the question then you need to tell [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) about it. By default is uses quotes (`"`) as `$enclosure`.

Answer (score 0):

Tips:
`str_getcsv` does not know that the first row of your csv file contains your column names.
`str_getcsv` does not need "," in the statement `str_getcsv($abbrev_list, ",")` because , is default separator.
Statement `$expand_abbrev=...`  has no idea what you're arguments mean.
You must write a `foreach` to create array `$contracted_form` using `$test`.
You must write a `foreach` to create array `$expanded_form` using `$test`.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understood you want to put each line of the csv into a multi dimensional array, if I understood you wrong please correct me.

Also bare in mind the algorithm below does not take into csv headers into account.

```
// The Multidimensional Array
$array = array();
$handle = fopen("file.csv", "r");
// If csv if empty, this will not run
while((($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, ',')) !== false)) {
    // The "magic" happen here.
    temp = array();
    $temp["contrated_form"] = $data[0];
    $temp["expanded_form"]  = $data[1];

    array_push($array, $temp);
}
```

For example if your csv file had the following:

```
data1,data2
data3,data4
data5,data6
```

The result of the above algorithm would be:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
       [contrated_form] => data1
       [expanded_form] => data2 
   ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
       [contrated_form] => data3
       [expanded_form] => data4 
   ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
       [contrated_form] => data5
       [expanded_form] => data6 
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Sorry I guess you aright, I did not supply an example of what I would like to achieve. Here it comes, I would the out put to be something on these lines:

array([contracted_form] => Abd., [expanded_form] =< Aberdeen)

So that when preg_replace finds the abbreviation Abd., in a string, it will replace it with Aberdeen.

Do you think there is away to achieve it ?

Comment: @KennethBorg post it on your question

Comment: @KennethBorg that is not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Do you know how can I get it to work then please ?

Comment: @KennethBorg can you post the expected result in your answer so its easier for us to read. Please

Comment: I have added more detail to the question and added an example as well.