# How to pass standard php functions to array_map and array_filter?

Tags: php

PHP functions such as `array_map` and `array_filter` take an array, and a function as arguments.

EG:

```
$result = array_map(function (el) {
// do stuff
}, $elements)
```

Is it possible to pass a standard php function the same way?

Something along the lines of `$result = array_map(boolval, $elements)`

**EDIT**
The above example throws the error `Undefined constant boolval`

Comment: why not ? give it a try!

Comment: Undefined constant `boolval`

Comment: It should be : `$result = array_map('boolval', $elements);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function (user-defined OR builtin) name as a string in the parameter of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

Do the following:

```
$result = array_map('boolval', $elements);
```

Comment: That works! is there any way to get the actual callable object boolval, other than by passing it's name in a string?

Comment: @indieman If you specifically want a function instead of just a string, you could wrap the builtin function in a closure, like `$boolval = function($x) { return boolval($x); };`. I really can't think of any context where this would be needed, though. A callable type declaration should always convert the string to its corresponding function.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you just run

```
$result = array_map('functionName', $array);
```

If it's a class function, you have to pass the object instance and the function name in an array.

```
$result = array_map([$objectInstance, 'functionName'], $array);
```

If the function is in the same class, then

```
$result = array_map([$this, 'functionName'], $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have any function which take a `callable` as a parameter PHP function is passed by its name as a string. And any `PHP built-in` or `user-defined` function can be used, except language constructs such as: `array()`, `echo`, `empty()`, `eval()`, `exit()`, `isset()`, `list()`, `print` or `unset()`. You can read more here [PHP Callbacks/Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

You can call any function by passing it name as a first parameter of `call_user_func_array` and second parameters an array with parameters that the function you want to call take

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_map', array(
    'boolval', array(
        "1", 
        '0', 
        true, 
        false
    )
));
```